# Office 2016 keep adding icons to task bar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, microsoft-office-2016

I've installed Office 2016, on a Windows 10 PC
All users that logon get Outlook, excel, and word icons in the task bar.

If I remove those icons, and reboot they reappear, even when using a local admin account.
Is Office 2016 doing this Out of the box? I'm very confused, I have no GPO doing it.

I tried rightclick unpin
and I also tried deleting them from: 
%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
both from within an Admin Account. they keep being added on restart.

[image]

Comment: do you want a screenshot of the task bar?
eh .. okay.. but its just a normal taskbar with Office Icons.

Comment: It might be more useful to describe how you remove the icons from the task bar in the first place.

Comment: post editted about how I tried to delete

Comment: Having the same issue here at work. Been trying to figure it out. Drives me crazy because I only have a set amount of space and the icons makes it overflow....every morning.Rest assured, I'm going to figure this out if it kills me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Open Start menu
- Right-click the application you want removed from your task bar,
- Then, "more > Remove from Task bar"

Comment: Not helpful. As mentioned in the question, they reappear after reboot.